# On received response, updated input fields using set timeout

Tags: angular

I have two input fields :

```
        <input tabindex="5" type="password" class="form-control" name="newPsw" [(ngModel)]="newPassword"" (ngModelChange)=" checkPassword()">
        <input tabindex="5" type="password" class="form-control" name="newPsw" [(ngModel)]="newPassword"" (ngModelChange)=" checkPassword()">
```

After callin checkPassword and updating the password I have a function :

```
    changePasswordResult(success: boolean) {
   this.passwordUpdated = success;
   if (success) {
   setTimeout(function() {
    this.confirmPassword = '';
    this.newPassword = '';
  }, 15000);
 }
```

}

What I was trying to do is clear the fields when success is received as true, but it is not setting their value to empty.
How do I fix this ?

Comment: Well, are you waiting 15 seconds to for the effect to happen? Also, `setTimeout` executes the function from a different context, therefore `this` will no longer refer to your component. **But**, you can add `setTimeout` the parameter `this` and use it in the function as `function(comp) { comp.confirmPassword = ''; }`

Comment: Ezra,could you please be more specific? What exactly you wanted to do? Need to update the newPassword after 15s?

Comment: What I wanted to do, is after 15 seconds that I get the response to be true, to clear out those two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that `setTimeout` executes the function from a different context. This is just the tip of the fork, but the `this` variable refers in some way to that context.

A little bit of reading about it can be very helpful: [this - Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

What you can do, is forward `this`, which refers to your component, to the `setTimeout` function, and use it as a variable inside your callback.

```
changePasswordResult(success: boolean) {
   this.passwordUpdated = success;
   if (success) {
   setTimeout(function(comp) {
    comp.confirmPassword = '';
    comp.newPassword = '';
  }, 15000, this);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens because you are using 'function' and have the wrong context 'this'. You need to use arrow functions or save context before setTimeout function. 
http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis

Answer (score 0):

```
changePasswordResult(success: boolean) {
   this.passwordUpdated = success;
   if (success) {
   setTimeout(()=> {
    this.confirmPassword = '';
    this.newPassword = '';
  }, 15000);
 }

Try above code or you can use ChangeDetectorRef also
Just import this into your file 
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
then add private ref: ChangeDetectorRef into constructor
Then put this code
changePasswordResult(success: boolean) {
   this.passwordUpdated = success;
   if (success) {

    this.confirmPassword = '';
    this.newPassword = '';
     this
        .ref
        .detectChanges();
 }
```